# strange printf() behavior in Java

Tags: java, printf, string-formatting

I have the following code fragment

```
System.out.printf("%b\n", 123);
```

which prints "true".

Can somebody explain this behavior? shouldn't this throw a IllegalFormatException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well since the specification says:

"If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by String.valueOf(). Otherwise, the result is "true". " ([src](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html))

The behavior is quite expected isn't it? Why they decided to implement it that way - no idea, I'd agree that it's not intuitive (but well it follows C which also prints just anything if you give it the wrong arguments ;) )

Comment: so, the 123 is boxed? or is it treated as a regular int?

Comment: @Mahmoud: As `printf` takes an `Object...` as the last parameter, all primitive arguments are boxed, yes. But anything which is not a boolean (or `null`) would get formatted to `"true"` here.

Answer (score 2):

From the JavaDocs:

> If the argument arg is null, then the result is "false". If arg is a boolean or Boolean, then the result is the string returned by String.valueOf(). Otherwise, the result is "true".

The argument you're giving it isn't `null`, `boolean`, or `Boolean`, so it falls under "Otherwise" and therefore is `true`